# DOMPDF fails to render images, outputs truncated files

Tags: php, pdf, dompdf

First things first:

- `DOMPDF_ENABLE_REMOTE` is set to `true` and seems to work since I do get the remote CSS loaded
- `DOMPDF_TEMP_DIR` is set to [`sys_get_temp_dir()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sys-get-temp-dir.php) and checked with [`is_writable()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-writable.php) - I can see the PHP session files there as well as some files like `ca_dompdf_img_Dl2XSR` that have 0 bytes size
- The GD extension is enabled according to [`phpinfo()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.phpinfo.php)
- If I pass the HTML code directly to browser (instead of DOMPDF) I can see the images

The `DOMPDF_LOG_OUTPUT_FILE` file has nothing useful.

Tried passing both:

- *direct http:// url* (server does not require auth) as well as
- *absolute path* on the filesystem (confirmed it's [`is_readable()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-readable.php) and seen by [`getimagesize()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getimagesize.php))

Here's what's weird: when I pass the absolute path, the temp files in the `DOMPDF_TEMP_DIR` are created empty, i.e. 0 bytes, and the PDF shows me `image not found`.

Now, if I pass the URL to the image, the temp files are not empty. If I download one of those files and add the `.jpg` extension, those are opened as normal JPEGs. The PDF itself shows me *This PDF document might not be displayed correctly* in Firefox and crashes in Adobe Reader.

When I open the PDF in the text editor, I can see the following:

```
BT 126.710 613.952 Td /F1 9.6 Tf  [(http://example.com/img/123.jpg )] TJ ET
```

Note that it has a space right after `.jpg` that is not present in the HTML I'm passing. The file also has some `stream` section which looks like the raw jpeg code. Then the file gets truncated for some reason.

Again, if I pass the absolute path the PDF is rendered OK, it's just the images are not there. In case of the URL, it fails to render completely. Feels like the issues are somehow connected.

What might be causing the issue?

Comment: The `Notice (8): Array to string conversion [APP/Vendor/dompdf/include/style.cls.php, line 2428]` code is gone after I've disabled the CSS debugging

Comment: seems like a server issue - asked here: http://serverfault.com/questions/661729/dompdf-php-truncates-the-output